# Where should I ask a beginner question about Git/GitHub

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm planning an open source project where I want to create several projects which extends each other. But I want the option to change a common base class which should be merged with its parent project but only that shared files the extensions without common files should be independent.

This are some basics questions, but where should I ask that?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a particularly beginner use of git, FWIW...

Comment: I never published a project. Now I have that project idea, but I'm not familar with GitHub (at the moment I even don't know how to commit some changes or how to merge two branches.) In the mean time I wrote [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18934079/995926).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are talking about a specific tool that you're using (not really a general way of doing something), it would most likely fall under Stack Overflow - it's about [tools commonly used by software programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

[image]

To make it more suitable for Stack Overflow, consider placing what specific you want done - diagrams and examples help!  Contrary to what some say though, not all questions require code on Stack Overflow, but effort is most *certainly* required.

Answer (score 4):

Since [good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) Stack Overflow question contain code, I would post it on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) because it's more about [concepts](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about) and design than actual programming.

When you have decided on your design and your implementation is misbehaving you should post on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).